# Parable of Talents -Mt. 25 (& Mina, Lk 19) - Was the wicked servant condemned for the inaction/no profit, or more for the independent mindset?

Tags: soteriology, parables, synoptics

Though he did not bring in any profit - so the thief on the cross and many of us as well; at least, he did not squander away the principle, after all, he too was "the servant," a trusted, as the others were.

-Does the judgment as written in the context (both parables) refer to the loss of one's salvation?

**Text: Mt 25:24 -26, 30 (Lk 19)(ESV):**

> “ 24 He also who had received the one talent came forward, saying,
> ‘Master, I knew you to be a hard man, reaping where you did not sow,
> and gathering where you scattered no seed, 25 so I was afraid, and I
> went and hid your talent in the ground. Here, you have what is yours.’
> 26 But his master answered him, ‘You wicked and slothful servant! And
> cast the worthless servant into the outer darkness. In that place
> there will be weeping and gnashing of teeth."

Comment: The wicked servant was condemned for not using what he was given as a servant - he did not perform his function as a servant.

Comment: If sending to eternal hell fire doesn't seem like losing the blessings or hope of eternal life. I don't think what would. I remember your answer to my question "Least in the kingdom means hell".

Answer (score 3):

The important verse here is Matt 25:30 -

> And throw that worthless servant into the outer darkness, where there
> will be weeping and gnashing of teeth.’

Note the parallels of this description with they fate of the wicked elsewhere such as Matt 8:12, 13:42, 22:13, 24:51, Luke 13:28, etc.  This strongly suggests an eternally doomed person.

Benson correctly observes:

> Matthew 25:30. And cast ye the unprofitable servant — Who has so
> wickedly abused my goodness; into outer darkness — The darkness which
> is without the heavenly city, even the horrible darkness of hell.
> There, instead of the light and joy possessed by those who are
> admitted to the marriage- supper of the Lamb, shall be weeping and
> gnashing of teeth — Through the worm that dieth not, and the fire that
> is not quenched. There shall be the weeping of the careless,
> thoughtless sinner, and the gnashing of teeth of the proud and
> stubborn. See notes on Matthew 8:12; Matthew 13:42; Matthew 22:13. But
> why does this servant meet with this punishment? What had he done? It
> is true he had not done good. But neither is he charged with doing any
> harm. Why, for this reason, for barely doing no harm, he is consigned
> to outer darkness. He is pronounced a wicked, because he was a
> slothful, an unprofitable servant. So mere harmlessness, on which many
> build their hope of salvation, was the cause of his damnation! Observe
> this well, reader; slothful servants, who do nothing with respect to
> the purpose of their being sent into the world, nothing to answer the
> end of their birth and baptism, who are no way serviceable to the
> glory of God, or the good of others, will be reckoned with as
> unprofitable servants. A slothful servant is a withered member in the
> body, a barren tree in the vineyard, an idle drone in the hive, that
> is good for nothing. In one sense, indeed, we are all unprofitable
> servants, Luke 17:10. We cannot profit God, Job 22:2; but to others,
> and to ourselves, it is required that we be profitable; and if we be
> not, Christ will not own us as his servants.

Comment: Such a false statement by Bensen, "we are all unprofitable" and cannot profit God. This goes against the Parable teaching itself. Proverbs 19:17: “Whoever is generous to the poor lends to the LORD, and he will repay him for his deed.”. God is a loan shark and an investment banker. He sends to hell for not profiting him.

Comment: @Michael16 - I disagree with your caricature and over-simplification.  However, I would be interested in your own answer.  Further, I believe the "talents" in the parable actually represent the grace of God which, if unused, results in condemnation by spurning the free salvation gifted to all.

Comment: I agree with your answer and upvoted. The lawless servant is sent to hell fire. You can call it grace and mercy and even superfluously call it free. It changes nothing. The parables say what it says. Whole ministry of Jesus aimed at exposing the faith alone dead religion of the hypocrites. This is why Christians avoid Jesus teachings the most. Nothing is new under the sun.

Comment: The reason why Jesus uses real life stories in illustration to show slave and master relations is bec God is the King and men are his slaves. Or God acts like the master and expects from us the same profit as the earthly business men, banks and institutions expect. The parables are not caricature. Luke 19:13: “Calling ten of his servants, he gave them ten minas, and said to them, ‘Engage in business until I come.’”

Answer (score 2):

In order to lose salvation, one has to first have had salvation.

If one never had salvation, they could never lose it.

You can only lose something you already have.

Does the parable of the wicked servant say anywhere that he was 'saved'? No. What it does say is that Jesus had come to seek and to save "that which was lost" (v.10). He came to his own, the people of Israel. Then he would go to a "far country to receive for himself a kingdom, and to return" (v.12). The unprofitable servant was in the household of that Master. This could allude to all Israelites being in the household of God due to being in his covenant. They 'belonged' to God, who viewed them as his people - Exodus 6:7 & Leviticus 26:12. In readiness for the Messiah coming to them, John the Baptist was sent "to make ready a people prepared for the Lord" - Luke 1:17. Then, shortly before Jesus' parable of the unprofitable servant in Luke chapter 19, he gave this parable to his disciples, in answer to the question, "Lord, are there few that be saved?" (Luke 13:23) ***This parable addresses the matter of salvation, so here are the relevant bits:***

> "Strive to enter in at the strait gate: for many, I say unto you, will
> seek to enter in, and shall not be able. When once the master of the
> house is risen up, and hath shut to the door, and ye begin to stand
> without, and to knock at the door saying 'Lord, Lord, open unto us',
> and he shall answer and say unto you, 'I know you not whence ye
> are'... depart from me, all ye workers of iniquity. There shall be
> weeping and gnashing of teeth when ye shall see Abram, and Isaac, and
> Jacob, and all the prophets, in the kingdom of God, and you yourselves
> thrust out." Luke 13:23-28

Those words were addressed to Israelites, and he referred them to their Jewish forebears who would get into the Kingdom, but not so, people who worked iniquity.

Coming back to Luke chapter 19, the uprofitable servant was a worker of iniquity due to his malign attitude towards his Master. Had he thought better of his Master, he would not have treated what he was entrusted with contemptuously. He tried to blame his Master (upon his return), accusing his Master of being a hard man, and dishonest to boot. The Master did not argue with the servant, who had shown himself to have a heart of stone. He saw him for what he truly was. Jesus had warned that "by our words we will be judged" (and vs. 22), so with this servant. His own words of accusation were hurled back at him.  He had proved himself to be an enemy of the Master, rebelling against his Master's rule over him. Therefore, he was cast out, to experience weeping and gnashing of teeth.

The primary application of this was to the people of Israel. When their Messiah returns, in kingly glory, they will be judged, with some having been faithful and done good (spiritual) business on behalf of their Master. Those who despise and resent him will be cast into outer darkness, for they never were saved in the first place and refused to have the salvation of the Messiah.

In principle, this also applies to the whole world of mankind, for Gentiles were then invited into the Kingdom, and when the King returns, all the nations will be gathered before him and judged. Many will be thrown out. Others will know the joy of their Master.

**In answer to your primary question:** ***"[What] was the wicked servant condemned for?"*** That wicked servant was condemned for his rebellion against, and hatred of, his master, the returned King. ***That internal attitude of mind and state of heart led to his resentful inactivity on behalf of his Master***. He did not have "an independent mindset" because the parable in Luke 13 shows that he will be in company of "many" who thought similarly, and who likewise will be cast out for weeping and gnashing of teeth.

**In answer to your secondary question:** ***"Does the judgment as written... refer to the loss of one's salvation?"*** ***No, it refers to never gaining salvation***.

Comment: Up-voted +1. The man had a 'heart of stone' - there were impenetrable parts within him, and there was not enough depth. Repentance had not gone deep enough, to eliminate the rocky parts of the heart. (cf the parable of the sower.)

Comment: @Anne -what about the other two profitable servants Jesus complemented?

Comment: @Sam  The other two profitable servants do not come into this question as originally asked. It only asks about the unprofitable servant. If you want to ask about the other two, you will need to post a new question, as this site is only meant to deal with one question at a time, and the comment boxes are only for suggesting improvements to existing Qs and As. So, my suggestion is that you post a fresh question!

Answer (score 1):

#### Was the wicked servant condemned for, the inaction/no profit, or more for the independent mindset?

In a way, yes on both counts.

First, as a servant (or slave), each is to be responsible for doing what his master asks and promoting the interests of his master.

In the topic of "[Illustrations](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200002147#h=89)" in the *Insight on the Scriptures*, we get a clear explanation of the servants' behavior:

> The slaves should all have been interested in the master’s estate and so should have traded diligently and wisely with the master’s goods committed to their care. The least they should have done was to deposit the money with the bankers, so that, if they did not themselves want to increase their master’s goods, the money would not lie completely idle but would earn interest. But the wicked and sluggish slave hid in the ground the talent committed to him, thereby, in effect, working against his master’s interests.

Secondly, the wicked servant tried to justify his actions and, in effect, blame his master for his own wicked behavior.

The [October 1, 1974 issue](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/pc/r1/lp-e/1200020040/789/0) of *The Watchtower* highlights this:

> In his negative thinking this slave tried to justify himself when the accounting was made. He tried to place wrongdoing on his lord. He charged his lord with getting crops, not only from his own land, but also from land he had not cultivated, and gathering grain that he had not winnowed of its chaff.

So because of his inactions and his attitude, the wicked servant was cast out into the darkness.

**Does the judgment as written in the context (both parables) refer to the loss of one's salvation?**

It most certainly can. Reading on in the chapter, Jesus talks about the final judgment in which some will be destroyed.

> Then he will say to those on his left, ‘Depart from me, you cursed, into the eternal fire prepared for the devil and his angels. (vs 41 ESV)

Comment: Your second point -tried to blame his master, etc.(quote from the Watch Tower, 1974 issues) is interesting if is your personal opinion. But, as the official view of the Watch Tower, it only attests to another off-base interpretation by them. Therefore, NO source citation would be better for the Watch Tower organization and its namesake. In his answer, the servant shows he is wrong about the master, for he said - " I KNEW YOU TO BE A HARD MAN" etc. And, he said,  "I did x 3 -   "SO IWAS AFRAID; I WENT and  (I) HID." (cf. Adam blamed God -"the woman YOU gave" - Gen 3: 12).

Answer (score 0):

In order to address the OP’s question, it is important to lay out my interpretation of the characters and elements in this passage of Mathew (25:14-30). The master who leaves and returns is understood to be Christ. The servants are the disciples of Christ who are entrusted with, to varying degrees, his gospel and grace. The settling of the servant’s accounts regards the final judgment of souls.

There are two themes that stand out in the text. One regards the nature of Christ’s gifts. Jesus gives us of his wealth, and what we receive is meant to produce profit/fruit (cf Mt 13:23). The other theme centers around the unprofitable servant’s lack of knowledge regarding the master. This ignorance is evident in his excuse for burying the money and is accentuated by the irony in his words, “Master, I knew you.”

> ‘Master, I knew you to be a hard man, reaping where you did not sow,
> and gathering where you did not scatter seed. 25 And I was afraid, so
> I went away and hid your talent in the ground.’ – vv 24-25

The master repudiated the servant’s words, pointing out that if the servant had wanted to preserve the principle, he could have simply put the money in the bank to at least earn interest. Burying the money in the ground was thus shown to be an act of laziness or worse, of deliberate obstruction.

> “But his master answered and said to him, ‘You worthless, lazy slave!
> Did you know that I reap where I did not sow, and gather where I did
> not scatter seed? 27 Then you ought to have put my money in the bank,
> and on my arrival I would have received my money back with interest. –
> vv 26-27

Despite the servant’s asserting that he knew the master, his excuse was rife with inconsistencies and misconceptions. Accusing the master of gathering where he did not scatter, the servant overlooked the fact that it was the master who gave him the principle in the first place. And although he portrayed the master as greedy and demanding, at no point in the story do the actions of the master evince these attributes. When a servant is faithful, instead of taking from them, the master gives them even more.

> His master said to him, ‘Well done, good and faithful slave. You were
> faithful with a few things, I will put you in charge of many things” –
> vv 21 & 23
>
> For to everyone who has, more shall be given, and he will have an
> abundance – v 29

Regarding the OP’s first question, the text does not offer a clear answer. The servant’s action/inaction and his mindset are like two sides of the same coin and are difficult to separate and parse. His burying of Christ’s gifts betrayed his mindset, and his attitude/mindset is in itself a manifestation of the absence or suppression of grace (cf Eph 4:13).

**Lessons from the parable and support from other passages**

Christ’s gifts are not meant to be buried or hidden away (cf Mt 5:15-16) but to yield profit/fruit.

> But the one sown with seed on the good soil, this is the one who hears
> the word and understands it, who indeed bears fruit and produces, some
> a hundred, some sixty, and some thirty times as much. – Mt 13:23

His gifts are given for our salvation, provided we work together with him.

> And working together with Him, we also urge you not to receive the
> grace of God in vain— 2 for He says, “At a favorable time I listened
> to you, And on a day of salvation I helped you.” – 2 Cor 6:1

Our response to Christ’s gifts has direct implications both in the here and now and at the final judgment. The reward of the faithful servants was an invitation to “enter the joy of your master” (vv 21 & 23). These words offer a new perspective and framework for understanding salvation. Regarding the OP’s second question, one wonders whether the unprofitable servant, filled as he was with fear ( v 25) and resentment, had ever tasted of that joy.

> Already the one who reaps is receiving wages and is gathering fruit
> for eternal life, so that the one who sows and the one who reaps may
> rejoice together. – Jn 4:36

Ultimately, it is not what we do, but what we allow Christ’s gifts to do in us and through us that determines our profitability as servants (cf 1 Cor 15:10). These texts challenge us to recognize and honor this subtle yet significant distinction. We are merely God’s fellow workers. It is God who provides the principle, the growth and the increase.

> So then neither the one who plants nor the one who waters is anything,
> but God who causes the growth. 8 Now the one who plants and the one
> who waters are one; but each will receive his own reward according to
> his own labor. 9 For we are God’s fellow workers – 1 Cor 3:7-9
>
> For in this case the saying is true: ‘One sows and another reaps.’ I
> sent you to reap that for which you have not labored; others have
> labored, and you have come into their labor. – Jn 4:37-38

**Thoughts on the thief who was crucified with Jesus**

He did not receive God’s grace in vain. When many others were blind, he was able to see Jesus for who he really is – the means of his salvation (cf Jn 17:3).